# How to fix "Drop to root Shell Prompt"?

Tags: boot, recovery-mode

I cannot load the ubuntu through the normal boot. So, I am trying to work on that by "Drop to root shell prompt" in the recovery mode. But, when I try to write anything I see diamond characters? How can I solve that? (Left-bottom of the following image)

[image]

Comment: Have you already pressed Enter at this point?

Comment: @Levente No, but it doesn't accept anything. For example, when I enter my password at this stage the answer is: "command not found"

Comment: Appreciaye any tips. It looks like ubuntu is trying to start another program, alacritty, instead of bash